# Number of different combinations in a sample

Tags: sample, discrete-data

I hail from Mathematica SE. A friend of mine asked me a statistics question (I'm an economist and am assumed to know such things) which kind of stumped me, since I usually deal with non-discrete statistics.

Say you have a DNA strand with 20 positions, each of which can have one of four nucleotides (A,C,G,T). There is a "correct" combination, say A,T,G,C,C,....

For each position the probability of having the correct nucleotid is 85%. The probability of having one of the others is 5% each.

Now assume you have a sample of 100M strands. My question is : **What is the most likely number of different combinations (20 nucleotides in a specific order) in our sample?**

Bonus question: Could you point me to some further reading on the subject, as I am interested in refreshing my memory on discrete statistics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to supply more information. What exactly do you mean by a "combination"? Should we assume all the probabilities at all the positions are independent?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. By combination I mean a sequence of 20 letters (one letter for each position). All the probabilities at all the positions are indeed independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** the *expected* number of distinct sequences is around ten million, getting *the most likely* number of distinct sequences is not easy, and Knuth's Concrete Mathematics is a good book on the topic.

I can give you the expected number of different combinations, this is one is easy because expectation is linear. Let $a_i$ be the random variable which is $1$ is combination $i$ is in the sample, and $0$ otherwise. $m = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$ is a random variable which represents the number of distinct combinations present in the sample. Clearly $m \leq n=4^{20}$.

Now the part which still amazes me to this day... $E(m) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n p(a_i=1)$

So what is the probability that a particular combination is sampled? It depends on the number of correct nucleotides. One combinaiton has all the nucleotides correct and is sampled with probability $0.85^{20} = q^k$ (in the future, $q=0.85$ and $k=20$).

There are also $3k$ combinations where one nucleotide is wrong, and each has a probability $\frac{1}{3}(1-q)q^{k-1}$ of being picked.

In general there are $3^r {k \choose r}$ combinations where $r$ nucleotides are wrong, each with a probability $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^r(1-q)^r q^{k-r}$ of being picked.

As a sanity check

$$\sum_{r=0}^k 3^r {k \choose r} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^r(1-q)^r q^{k-r} = 1$$

For each possible combination, we get $N=10^8$ tries. This gives us the expectation

$$E(m) = \sum_{r=0}^k 3^r {k \choose r} \left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^r(1-q)^r q^{k-r} \right)^N\right)$$

numerically, this is about $1.03 \times 10^7$ about one hundred thousandth of the total number of combinations.

---

The *most likely* number of distinct combinations is harder to obtain. One route would be to compute the probability of obtaining exactly $d$ distinct elements with $d = d_0 + d_1 + \ldots + d_r$  distinct elements having respectively $d_i$ distinct elements with $i$ incorrect nucleotides.

When the probabilities are uniform, the probability is given by 
$$\frac{1}{n^N} d!{n \choose d}\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{N}{d}$$
where $\genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{N}{d}$ is a Stirling number of the second kind and represents the number of way to partition the $N$ draws in $d$ non empty subsets. Intuitively, that formula simply counts the number of draws with $d$ distinct elements by saying: pick $d$ distinct elements, order them and assign them to different partitions of the sample.

Let's put it all together, we get

$$p(d) = \sum_{\substack{d_0+\ldots+d_k=d \\ N_0+\ldots+N_k=N}} \left(  N! \prod_{r=0}^{k}  \genfrac\{\}{0pt}{}{N_r}{d_r} {3^r{k \choose r} \choose d_r} \frac{d_r!}{N_r!}\left(\left(\frac{1-q}{3}\right)^r q^{k-r}\right)^{N_r} \right)$$

Note that there are on the order of $(dn)^k$ terms in that sum. You could *conceivably* approximate it using Monte-Carlo integration with importance sampling, evaluate this for multiple values of $d$ and find the location of the maximum this way. A good approach would be to sample $d_1, \ldots, d_k$ and $N_1, \ldots, N_k$ using two multinomial distributions and adapt the parameters of these distributions using the cross-entropy method.

---

Discrete statistics involve a lot of combinatorial enumeration. A very enjoyable book on the topic is Knuth's [Concrete Mathematics](http://smile.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1415804782&sr=8-1&keywords=concrete%20mathematics)

Comment: Hmm, that was not the full response I had typed. I wanted to know what $E(m)$ entails exactly. Isn't this the expected number of distinct sequences in a single 100M sample? I will accept your answer as well. :)

Comment: Yes, it is the expected number of distinct sequences in a single 100M sample. That is, if you repeat the procedure of drawing a 100M sample and counting the number of distinct sequences many times, on average there will be E(m) distinct sequences.

Comment: If you offered to pay a dollar for each distinct sequence you're going to get in a 100M sample, the fair value of that contract would be E(m)

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit at the top. Great. Thanks again. I'll give that reading a go when I have a bit more spare time.
Cheers